# Angular Universal Transfer State API

Tags: angular, express, angular-universal

I'm trying to complete the project that will work best with SEO.
So i found out about Angular Universal and manage to make it work.
And then i see so many article that talk about Transfer State API.

Now i'm having trouble understanding the Transfer State API.

I don't understand the concept of Angular Transfer State API
I don't get it, why should be on the project.

Can someone please explain to me why Transfer State API is needed to be on the project?

Thank you so much

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61192014/1160794

Comment: @David Is there the way to detect where the web is render by browser or server?

Comment: Yes, use isPlatformBrowser, like in question in the link

Comment: @David Thank for the reply, i also read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44261914/angular-universal-server-side-requests-cached-for-client is it related to this transfer state api? i'm so confused now.